# Stored procedure accept table name from user read table structure in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Actually I want to write a stored procedure in mysql that accepts a column name from user. In the stored procedure checked given table present or not in database if present then accept only value (without known column name) from user and insert that value into table.

I wrote following code please help me to solve this problem

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `mySP`(IN tName INT(15),IN val INT(15))
--parameter details
-- tname =accept table name from user 
-- val = accept value from user to insert
-- store =get query result 
BEGIN
 DECLARE 
store varchar(30);

set store =(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'student');
if(tNAme=store )
select case 
while column.datatype=INT then insert into TableName(abc);
while column.datatype=varchar then insert into TableName(abc);


END
```

Comment: accept any values from user

Comment: Can you publish the student table definition please.

Comment: Use `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and the datasize of the `TABLE_NAME` column is 256. So don't restrict the `store` datasize as 30. Instead of that, use `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = tName)`

Comment: i try this but cant get outpute [  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insertData`(IN tablename varchar(20), IN tabledata TEXT)
BEGIN  

/*
Description:TODO code accept table name from user and 
read all tables and find match table after that read 
all column name from given table accessible

 */
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@tablename ,' VALUES (',@tabledata,')');   
 PREPARE stmt from @s;   
 EXECUTE stmt;   

END ]

Comment: @Arulkumar Your point is well made and should apply to tname as well, however, information_schema.columns table_name is VARCHAR(64) not VARCHAR(256).